# Saving in Background Thread not getting finished

Tags: ios, ios8, nsfilemanager, avaudiorecorder, dispatch-async

I have an instance of `AVAudioRecorder` and I have noticed that when the user closes the app too fast with a larger recording the file does not get saved properly.

This even happens when I call `[recorderObject stop]` in the main thread and the file gets saved locally.

I have also tried moving the file after the recording has stopped (in the `(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:` method). But I have noticed that when I do the move with `NSFileManager` in a background thread with `high` priority, it too doesn't always finish.

Is there a way for me to insure that the files get saved, even if the user exits the app shortly after finishing a longer recording?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to ask iOS for background task completion?https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for executing tasks in the background.

> Apps moving to the background are expected to put themselves into a
>   quiescent state as quickly as possible so that they can be suspended
>   by the system. If your app is in the middle of a task and needs a
>   little extra time to complete that task, it can call the
>   `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:` or
>   `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` method of the `UIApplication`
>   object to request some additional execution time. Calling either of
>   these methods delays the suspension of your app temporarily, giving it
>   a little extra time to finish its work. Upon completion of that work,
>   your app must call the endBackgroundTask: method to let the system
>   know that it is finished and can be suspended.

Comment: `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` was just what I was looking for. Thanks